# Java : Thread.sleep() in a thread : no wait

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, sleep

I have a problem with thread not sleeping.
I can't put here my whole code. so, to reproduce, here is a basic code waiting 5 seconds.

```
try {
    int millisec = 5000;
    System.out.println(new Date());
    System.out.println("We wait " + millisec + " milliseconds");
    Thread.sleep(millisec);
    System.out.println(new Date());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output :

Thu Aug 22 20:01:42 CEST 2013
We wait 5000 milliseconds
Thu Aug 22 20:01:47 CEST 2013

Everything is OK.
But when I put this code in a thread, no sleep. Example with this code :

```
try {
    Thread aThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int millisec = 5000;
                System.out.println(new Date());
                System.out.println("We wait " + millisec + " milliseconds");
                Thread.sleep(millisec);
                System.out.println(new Date());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    aThread.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output :

Thu Aug 22 20:07:30 CEST 2013
We wait 5000 milliseconds

...and nothing else, the thread is terminated.

I don't understand why. Please, any ideas ?

**EDIT** : I use Eclipse and JUnit to test.

Comment: Does your process itself stay alive beyond 5 seconds?

Comment: Your code works for me.  You sure your IDE isn't cutting off the output or something?

Comment: Works for me too, clean and try again.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, but just to be safe, try adding some more println statements after the sleep (just print a bunch of garbage).  Maybe your console is buffering the output for some reason.

Comment: I use Eclipse and Junit to test. If it's ok for you, the problem is in my IDE. I'll have a look. Thanks for your prompt replys !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

The issue turned out to be how JUnit works.  It does not know that background threads were spawned so when the test thread completes, it kills the rest of the threads without waiting for them.

---

Your code properly spits out both date lines when I try it in a small `main()` class.  Here are some possibilities as to why you aren't seeing the output in your application:

- The thread that is spawning the `aThread` may be a daemon thread itself.  The `aThread` is therefore daemon because its daemon status is gotten from the spawning thread's status.  If the JVM finishes *before* the 2nd `System.out.println(...)` the `aThread` will be killed.  If there is a question about it, you should do:

  ```
  Thread aThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  ...
  // ensure the deamon flag is off _before_ we start the thread
  aThread.setDaemon(false);
  aThread.start();
  ```
- Another possibility is that something is actually closing `System.out` before the 2nd `println(...);`.  Unlikely but possible.  Are you using shutdown hooks at all for cleanup?
- A third possibility is that the output is actually being printed but your IDE or your console is somehow not displaying the output.
- Another possibility is that the `System.out.println(...);` threw an `IOException`.  It might be interesting to check the value of `System.out.checkError()` to see if it is `true` although I'm not sure how you would then display it.

One thing to try is to create a temporary file instead of printing output.  Something like:

```
new File("/var/tmp/" + System.currentTimeMillis()).createNewFile();
```

Then you should see 2 files in `"/var/tmp"` (or wherever a temp directory on your OS is).

You should also try changing `System.out` to `System.err` to see if that changes anything.  Doubtful but worth a try.

If these don't work as well then something is killing the JVM forcefully so it can't wait for the background threads.

Comment: Possibility 1 : aThread.setDaemon(false) added, no change for me.

Comment: Possibility 3 : yes, I use Eclipse and JUnit, this could be the reason. Thanks !

Comment: There is actually another (unlikely) possibility: an `Error` is thrown somewhere which is not caught by `catch (Exception e)` and the thread is terminated silently

Comment: Good one @Katona.  Unlikely but possible.  The `System.out.println(...)` might also have thrown an internal exception that is being caught and blocked.  I've added that.

Comment: And another. If JUnit4 `@Test(timeout=...)` or `TimeOut` rule is used, then based on [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/FailOnTimeout.java) the entire test case is run within a daemon thread.

Comment: You did the `setDaemon(false)` _before_ the `start()` right @jack-y?  We are running out of options now.  Any chance something is killing the JVM?  Is it possibly crashing (yes unlikely)?  Are you sending the console output into a logfile?

Comment: I put the code in a main() and it works for me. It seems that my Eclipse + JUnit configuration is the problem. Thanks you all, great help !

Comment: @Gray, yes, added the `setDaemon(false)` before.

Comment: It's Junit @jack-y.  Junit does not know if threads are spawned and kills them when the test thread returns.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you didn't call join() in your main thread (if you using the JUnit then the thread calling the test case and creating the thread object).

Comment: You're right, adding `aThread.join()` after the start solves for the JUnit test. Unfortunately I can't put this in my production application. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Thread.join` works if you have one worker thread, else something like [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit) can help.